# How to plot a vector field with arrow length and background color for strength and direction

Tags: plotting, color, legending, vector, graphics

I want to visualize a 2D vector field, e.g.,

```
Table[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/4] {y, -x}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}]
```

in the following way:

- the arrow length denotes the vector length
- the background color indicates the local vector orientation
- the color becomes paler when the vector length decreases

Just something like the following. How can one achieve this in Mathematica?[image]

## **Edit**

Using the `Hue` method in the answer below, I tried the following case. There looks to be some obvious mismatch: the vectors are still quite big while the colors already decay to white.

```
rmax = 5.0; rmesh = 0.1;
data = Table[{{x, y}, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/0.5] {y, -x}}, {x, -rmax, rmax,
     rmesh}, {y, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}];
maxnorm = Max[Map[Norm[#[[2]]] &, data, {2}]]
data = MapAt[#/maxnorm &, data, {All, All, 2}];
vp2 = ListVectorPlot[data, 
  Prolog -> {Map[{If[#[[1]] == {0, 0}, Hue[0, 0, 1], 
        Hue[ArcTan[#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]]/(2 \[Pi]), Norm[#[[2]]], 1]],
        Rectangle[#[[1]] - rmesh/2, #[[1]] + rmesh/2]} &, data, {2}]},
   PlotRange -> rmax {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the requirements correctly, two ways you might be able to do it are using `RegionPlot` + `VectorPlot` or `Graphics` + `ListVectorPlot`. The first way is nice because you can continuously increase the resolution. The second way uses pre-calculated, discrete values which more closely match the example graphic.

```
rp = RegionPlot[
    -3 <= x <= 3 \[And] -3 <= y <= 3,
    {x, -3, 3},
    {y, -3, 3},
    BoundaryStyle -> None,
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[
       ArcTan[Exp[-(#1^2 + #2^2)/
            4] #2, -Exp[-(#1^2 + #2^2)/4] #1]/(2 \[Pi]), 
       Norm[Exp[-(#1^2 + #2^2)/4]], 1] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotPoints -> 200,
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
  ];
vp = VectorPlot[
    Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/4] {y, -x},
    {x, -3, 3},
    {y, -3, 3},
    VectorColorFunction -> None,
    VectorScaling -> Automatic,
    VectorStyle -> Black
  ];
Show[
  rp,
  vp
]
```

[image: Non-list version of colourful vector plot.]

The vectors go slightly outside of the plot, but the vectors could probably be adjusted to avoid that without too much difficulty. Here, the colourful background is provided by `RegionPlot`, and the the specific hue is controlled by the angle of the vector at a given point with the saturation controlled by the length of the vector. The brightness is 1 in all cases. As far as I can tell, that's how it worked in the example image so I tried to replicate that here. I think the `ArcTan` for the hue should be fine, but I'm not sure how robust using the `Norm` for the saturation will be. If the length of your vectors is greater than 1, the values for saturation will be clipped to 1, so keep that in mind.

We can also create a little colour wheel. This wheel can be added to either version, but here I've only added it to the discretized version of the plot.

```
wheel = RegionPlot[
  x^2 + y^2 <= 1,
  {x, -1, 1},
  {y, -1, 1},
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#1, #2]/(2 \[Pi]), Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2], 
      1] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Frame -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.15,
  Epilog -> {
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}],
    Line[{{0, #}, {0.05, #}}] & /@ {0, 0.5, 1},
    Text[Style[ToString[#], 16], {0.1, #}, {-1, 0}] & /@ {0, 0.5, 1}
    }
  ]
```

[image]

Then create our data points, make the plots, and add the wheel:

```
data = Table[
   {{x, y}, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/4] {y, -x}},
   {x, -3, 3, 0.2},
   {y, -3, 3, 0.2}
   ];
vp2 = ListVectorPlot[
  data,
  Prolog -> {
    Map[
     {
       If[
        #[[1]] == {0, 0},
        Hue[0, 0, 1],
        Hue[ArcTan[#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]]/(2 \[Pi]), Norm[#[[2]]], 1]
        ],
       Rectangle[#[[1]] - 0.1, #[[1]] + 0.1]
       } &,
     data,
     {2}
     ]
    },
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
  VectorColorFunction -> None,
  VectorScaling -> Automatic,
  VectorStyle -> Black,
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[
     wheel,
     {3, 3},
     {1.12, 1.12},
     Scaled[0.3]
     ]
    }
  ]
```

[image: Discretized version of the vector plot with background.]

In this one, I'm creating the background by using `Prolog` in the `ListVectorPlot` and creating a bunch of rectangles of the correct hue and saturation. `Prolog` plots things before the rest of the plot and `Epilog` plots things after everything is said and done.

**EDIT:**

I just realized that my `ListVectorPlot` wasn't actually plotting every vector. This is because Mathematica thinks that it's too crowded (it's probably not wrong). If you would like every point to plot, add `VectorPoints -> All` as an option in `ListVectorPlot` to get:

[image: Discretized vector plot with all points.]

**EDIT 2:**

```
rmax = 5.0; 
rmesh = 0.1; 
data = Table[
  {{x, y}, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/1] {y, -x}}, 
  {x, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}, 
  {y, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}
]; 
maxnorm = Max[Map[Norm[#[[2]]] &, data, {2}]];
data = MapAt[#/maxnorm &, data, {All, All, 2}];
vp2 = ListVectorPlot[
  data, 
  Prolog -> {Map[{If[#[[1]] == {0, 0}, Hue[0, 0, 1], 
        Hue[ArcTan[#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]]/(2 \[Pi]), Norm[#[[2]]], 1]],
        Rectangle[#[[1]] - rmesh/2, #[[1]] + rmesh/2]} &, data, {2}]},
  PlotRange -> rmax {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorScaling -> Automatic, 
  VectorSizes -> {0, 1}, 
  VectorStyle -> Black
]
```

[image: Vector Plot with VectorSizes -> {0, 1}.]

And with the option `VectorPoints -> All` added to the above code:

[image: Vector plot with VectorSizes and VectorPoints.]

**EDIT 3:**

Adding in `VectorRange`:

```
rmax = 5.0; 
rmesh = 0.1; 
data = Table[
  {{x, y}, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/1] {y, -x}}, 
  {x, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}, 
  {y, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}
]; 
maxnorm = Max[Map[Norm[#[[2]]] &, data, {2}]];
data = MapAt[#/maxnorm &, data, {All, All, 2}];
vp2 = ListVectorPlot[
  data, 
  Prolog -> {Map[{If[#[[1]] == {0, 0}, Hue[0, 0, 1], 
        Hue[ArcTan[#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]]/(2 \[Pi]), Norm[#[[2]]], 1]],
        Rectangle[#[[1]] - rmesh/2, #[[1]] + rmesh/2]} &, data, {2}]},
  PlotRange -> rmax {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorRange -> {0, 1},
  VectorScaling -> "Linear", 
  VectorSizes -> {0, 1}, 
  VectorStyle -> Black
]
```

[image: New vector plot.]

Comment: Thanks your code to show how to use `Hue`!

Comment: @cvgmt No problem!

Comment: Thank you! This is an almost perfect answer.

Comment: Could you please help look at the following code piece using your method? It looks weird that the arrows are still very big although the color almost disappears. I add a normalization of the vector length, by the way.
`rmax = 5.0; rmesh = 0.1;
data = Table[{{x, y}, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/1] {y, -x}}, {x, -rmax, rmax, 
    rmesh}, {y, -rmax, rmax, rmesh}];
maxnorm = Max[Map[Norm[#[[2]]] &, data, {2}]]
data = MapAt[#/maxnorm &, data, {All, All, 2}];`

Comment: `vp2 = ListVectorPlot[data, 
  Prolog -> {Map[{If[#[[1]] == {0, 0}, Hue[0, 0, 1], 
        Hue[ArcTan[#[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]]/(2 \[Pi]), Norm[#[[2]]], 1]],
        Rectangle[#[[1]] - rmesh/2, #[[1]] + rmesh/2]} &, data, {2}]},
   PlotRange -> rmax {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorStyle -> Black]`

Comment: @xiaohuamao You could try adding `VectorSizes -> {0, 1}` as an option to `ListVectorPlot`. It appears that there's a minimum size for the arrows by default and that's why they don't disappear at the edges.

Comment: Actually I tried that but it didn't work. What I mean is not the vector at the edge but the vector near or further than radius=2. They are as big as the center ones although the color already decays almost to white. It looks that the vector length has a mismatch with the color whiteness. In the figure in my original question, vector length and color whiteness seem to match quite well.

Comment: Please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: @xiaohuamao When I add `VectorSizes -> {0, 1}`, I get vectors of zero size at the edges. The code you just posted doesn't seem to have `VectorSizes -> {0, 1}` in it. I've posted an update of my own to show what I get. If you want them to show small dots like the original image, you could do something like `VectorSizes -> {0.05, 1}`.

Comment: I am not worrying about the edge. Both in your new figure or in mine, the vectors near or a bit further than radius=2  are as big as the center ones although the color already decays almost to white. This looks like a very conspicuous mismatch. But I don't find any vector/color like this in the original figure I posted.

Comment: In all our new figures, vectors are still big while the color is hardly discernible from white. Especially within the radius [1.5,3]. Nothing like this in the original figure I posted.

Comment: @xiaohuamao I think I understand what you mean now. Does the combination of `VectorScaling -> "Linear", VectorSizes -> {0, 1}, VectorRange -> {0, 1}` give closer to what you're thinking? I'll add what I get using that combination as an edit.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the right combination! I've tried `"Linear"` and `VectorSizes` only... To be honest, I still don't really understand from the documentation how those big vectors with almost white color come out. But the problem is solved as far as I can see.

Comment: @xiaohuamao I’m not completely sure, but I think maybe the vectors were ranging from say 0 to 2 or something, but it can’t actually make vectors larger than 1 so it made them all 1? Like some of those vectors near the centre should have been even bigger, or something. Kind of like when you plot that Gaussian without `PlotRange -> Full`, you get it being clipped rather than showing the rounded tip of the Gaussian. Just a guess, though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this.

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[
 Table[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorScaling -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
   Hue[If[vx == vy == 0, 0, ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π)]]], 
 VectorStyle -> Black, VectorColorFunction -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: `Hue[Arg[vx + I*vy]`

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I eventually also found this method very useful since it generates smooth colors in the background. But I notice [a weird issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241821/11125) recently.