# ListVectorDensityPlot plots outside the data in a very wrong way

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, vector

I am plotting a vector field data set `mydata` where the background color indicates the vector orientation and its opacity for the vector magnitude. I use `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), n]]` to get the rainbow-like color, in which `n` signifies the norm slot.

I conceived of two methods to plot it

- plot the original `mydata` with the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, False, False, True}` that presumably normalizes the norm to be within $[0,1]$
- normalize vectors with the maximal norm in `mydata` to get `mydatanormalized` and then just plot it with the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

```
mydata = ArrayReshape[#, {21, 21, 2}] &@ImportString[#, "List", "LineSeparators" -> " "] &@"-0.1053 0.1218 -0.1049 0.1505 -0.1375 0.1595 -0.1487 0.1927 -0.1451 0.2315 -0.1215 0.2768 -0.04844 0.3219 0.03322 0.3269 0.07211 0.2912 0.08432 0.2518 0.1131 0.2321 0.1724 0.2324 0.2272 0.2463 0.2196 0.2704 0.1544 0.2909 0.1152 0.2789 0.1279 0.2363 0.1452 0.1922 0.1434 0.1616 0.109 0.1527 0.09839 0.1137 -0.1213 0.136 -0.1614 0.1428 -0.1732 0.1841 -0.1728 0.2311 -0.1156 0.2995 -0.04907 0.2926 -0.1552 0.1407 -0.3534 -0.01118 -0.4592 -0.07593 -0.4765 -0.08614 -0.4852 -0.06397 -0.4895 -0.007719 -0.3949 0.06222 -0.1099 0.1005 0.2227 0.1192 0.2996 0.1942 0.1889 0.2662 0.1568 0.2377 0.1702 0.1815 0.1622 0.1482 0.122 0.1418 -0.1739 0.1208 -0.1922 0.1645 -0.1975 0.2172 -0.1333 0.291 -0.1719 0.1549 -0.4066 -0.1208 -0.3151 -0.1887 0.0631 -0.2345 0.2625 -0.3867 0.235 -0.5172 0.1542 -0.5666 0.08391 -0.545 -0.06646 -0.4208 -0.3682 -0.1554 -0.4933 0.08776 -0.06011 0.07589 0.3353 0.07367 0.2538 0.2236 0.1863 0.2226 0.192 0.159 0.1715 0.1322 -0.2041 0.1351 -0.22 0.1858 -0.173 0.2642 -0.2533 0.04761 -0.3845 -0.2177 0.1426 -0.1476 0.4323 -0.4011 0.01581 -0.6387 -0.3758 -0.4889 -0.4999 -0.2379 -0.5455 -0.1084 -0.6077 -0.1333 -0.5658 -0.3121 -0.2859 -0.5633 -0.1657 -0.4986 -0.4871 0.007491 -0.2228 0.1038 0.3369 -0.002831 0.2738 0.1983 0.2105 0.1894 0.2056 0.1288 -0.2311 0.1454 -0.218 0.2266 -0.2534 0.05052 -0.3389 -0.2386 0.3436 -0.07197 0.3474 -0.5235 -0.2275 -0.4495 -0.113 0.2096 0.2023 0.532 0.3474 0.5644 0.4112 0.5295 0.405 0.488 0.1526 0.4604 -0.4097 0.3655 -0.6207 -0.1181 -0.2755 -0.5577 -0.4798 0.004167 -0.1684 0.08243 0.3685 -0.02977 0.2602 0.1968 0.2284 0.1393 -0.253 0.1604 -0.2334 0.1419 -0.3543 -0.2607 0.271 0.01476 0.4151 -0.4706 -0.1293 -0.2393 0.129 0.5738 0.1148 0.5778 -0.09508 0.505 -0.116 0.5551 -0.004217 0.5867 0.1707 0.5495 0.423 0.4366 0.5743 0.3617 0.0175 0.5135 -0.618 0.1333 -0.3555 -0.5048 -0.5089 0.1697 0.08054 -0.06534 0.358 0.048 0.2506 0.1613 -0.2582 0.1718 -0.308 -0.1391 -0.05642 -0.07989 0.5825 -0.1667 0.008296 -0.3498 0.08211 0.6251 -0.1607 0.4409 -0.4303 0.4275 -0.3143 0.5939 -0.1327 0.6513 0.03406 0.6559 0.1883 0.6363 0.2908 0.5872 0.4234 0.4293 0.6435 0.2429 0.03715 0.5649 -0.579 -0.01969 -0.4309 -0.2641 -0.3364 0.195 0.3361 -0.16 0.2943 0.1476 -0.2673 0.1044 -0.3049 -0.2994 0.3626 0.1816 0.3727 -0.472 0.001924 0.4332 -0.1696 0.4304 -0.5591 0.2757 -0.4592 0.4918 -0.3519 0.5183 -0.2659 0.5616 -0.09348 0.6183 0.1314 0.5989 0.361 0.513 0.4824 0.4538 0.5533 0.2773 0.6248 0.2195 -0.2896 0.5875 -0.4982 -0.3974 -0.4863 0.2603 0.1407 -0.1899 0.3439 0.05582 -0.2786 -0.0324 -0.1941 -0.2044 0.5641 0.1394 0.1785 -0.2592 -0.05808 0.6511 -0.5027 0.08997 -0.6128 0.3006 -0.5299 0.3401 -0.5251 0.3802 -0.3475 0.5655 -0.01929 0.6477 0.2287 0.6177 0.3663 0.5083 0.5362 0.3325 0.5904 0.272 0.6829 0.03091 0.2214 0.5812 -0.5499 -0.08476 -0.4961 0.1056 -0.06765 -0.06919 0.359 -0.07163 -0.2761 -0.1554 -0.08473 -0.03167 0.6094 0.01855 0.07798 0.1012 -0.1947 0.4449 -0.6302 -0.03477 -0.6369 0.1938 -0.6219 0.13 -0.6111 0.2534 -0.303 0.4264 0.09962 0.3719 0.4239 0.3184 0.5455 0.3559 0.5647 0.234 0.648 0.131 0.6571 -0.03595 0.4996 0.3753 -0.4662 0.2026 -0.51 -0.00885 -0.1832 0.04382 0.3393 -0.171 -0.2615 -0.2213 -0.04926 0.07117 0.6149 0.00897 0.024 0.2857 -0.2641 0.2578 -0.6493 -0.1399 -0.6557 0.02893 -0.6399 -0.08074 -0.6387 -0.0007441 -0.3608 0.09465 0.007346 -0.0009028 0.3769 -0.08724 0.6345 0.03261 0.6116 0.06239 0.6586 -0.03337 0.6447 -0.1409 0.5834 0.2681 -0.3904 0.2822 -0.5222 0.009543 -0.2105 0.06824 0.3155 -0.2184 -0.2472 -0.2323 -0.0873 0.05752 0.5964 0.1293 0.04292 0.2784 -0.2628 0.2395 -0.5928 -0.2914 -0.6531 -0.1266 -0.5859 -0.2606 -0.5652 -0.3251 -0.4119 -0.3033 -0.08226 -0.3658 0.3187 -0.4094 0.6001 -0.2264 0.5953 -0.1647 0.6324 -0.1912 0.6217 -0.2794 0.5702 0.3252 -0.4316 0.1705 -0.4969 0.1579 -0.1811 -0.02403 0.3108 -0.2095 -0.245 -0.1963 -0.1483 -0.08369 0.4783 0.3497 0.2037 0.1327 -0.2708 0.4133 -0.4239 -0.4292 -0.6278 -0.2823 -0.5278 -0.3669 -0.4059 -0.5047 -0.2513 -0.5934 0.01406 -0.6254 0.3336 -0.5451 0.4879 -0.3919 0.5248 -0.3732 0.5617 -0.3413 0.6158 -0.3397 0.4355 0.488 -0.5753 -0.0458 -0.4104 0.3839 -0.1143 -0.2249 0.3265 -0.1465 -0.2622 -0.133 -0.1644 -0.2877 0.1814 0.5119 0.4972 0.03027 -0.2991 0.5835 -0.2053 -0.2953 -0.4827 -0.4978 -0.5046 -0.4433 -0.3522 -0.5418 -0.1633 -0.6184 0.04957 -0.6333 0.2286 -0.5891 0.3474 -0.5458 0.438 -0.4952 0.4755 -0.5012 0.6741 -0.06038 0.01007 0.4247 -0.6218 -0.0444 -0.306 0.4313 -0.0005853 -0.4014 0.3409 -0.07037 -0.2828 -0.0945 -0.1467 -0.3714 -0.1334 0.2989 0.537 0.2901 0.00376 0.3698 -0.293 0.2969 -0.1096 -0.5334 -0.3542 -0.6048 -0.3511 -0.5872 -0.1966 -0.6331 -0.02812 -0.6585 0.125 -0.6499 0.2403 -0.6243 0.3452 -0.608 0.6147 -0.312 0.4136 0.3586 -0.5743 0.03703 -0.3848 0.3885 -0.2612 0.01957 0.1751 -0.3491 0.321 -0.05854 -0.2716 -0.1112 -0.19 -0.258 -0.1576 -0.21 0.01572 0.5461 0.5296 0.2337 -0.2536 0.4973 -0.246 0.1792 0.08305 -0.4828 -0.007954 -0.6817 -0.07472 -0.702 -0.005609 -0.707 0.1391 -0.6944 0.3642 -0.6015 0.6275 -0.253 0.3941 0.2408 -0.4934 0.1225 -0.4678 0.2694 -0.2555 0.389 -0.117 -0.4085 0.316 -0.1561 0.2688 -0.114 -0.234 -0.1335 -0.2529 -0.1575 -0.09523 -0.3728 -0.2317 0.03112 0.07002 0.5562 0.4624 0.3282 -0.2308 0.4643 -0.4138 0.355 -0.009134 -0.03503 0.2844 -0.2779 0.4195 -0.3189 0.4808 -0.1992 0.368 0.038 -0.1098 0.1978 -0.6147 0.1328 -0.3873 0.3639 -0.2082 0.4786 -0.2768 -0.2929 0.2105 -0.2902 0.2958 -0.121 0.2281 -0.1462 -0.2065 -0.1259 -0.2296 -0.1659 -0.2005 -0.2228 -0.05204 -0.385 -0.2771 0.04309 -0.1131 0.5339 0.3871 0.4707 0.1428 0.4324 -0.3477 0.4414 -0.533 0.3754 -0.5441 0.3051 -0.5711 0.2708 -0.5883 0.2652 -0.407 0.3585 -0.1193 0.5688 -0.2342 0.377 -0.331 -0.2804 0.1355 -0.3338 0.3 -0.1523 0.2203 -0.1758 0.2069 -0.1301 -0.1755 -0.1277 -0.1917 -0.1584 -0.2112 -0.1947 -0.1623 -0.2553 -0.01455 -0.3841 -0.209 -0.159 -0.3922 0.292 -0.1193 0.5134 0.1762 0.5547 0.2226 0.5624 0.1554 0.5717 0.09772 0.5905 0.01863 0.5886 -0.1891 0.4332 -0.4181 0.01418 -0.2568 -0.3562 0.1765 -0.3024 0.2786 -0.1863 0.2019 -0.202 0.1944 -0.1618 0.1725 -0.1201 -0.1219 -0.1427 -0.1668 -0.1434 -0.1696 -0.1812 -0.1793 -0.2191 -0.154 -0.2562 -0.00981 -0.3511 0.00569 -0.3594 -0.2114 -0.2023 -0.4123 -0.01746 -0.4789 0.08845 -0.4855 0.09717 -0.4873 0.009834 -0.4405 -0.1557 -0.2497 -0.3138 0.06111 -0.3378 0.2535 -0.2536 0.221 -0.2233 0.1696 -0.226 0.1755 -0.1816 0.1603 -0.1414 0.1192 -0.138 -0.09769 -0.1143 -0.109 -0.1534 -0.1482 -0.1577 -0.1453 -0.1907 -0.137 -0.232 -0.139 -0.2565 -0.07987 -0.2917 0.03069 -0.3354 0.1005 -0.3555 0.11 -0.3516 0.1107 -0.3425 0.1407 -0.3325 0.1894 -0.3114 0.2091 -0.2807 0.1743 -0.2626 0.1346 -0.2582 0.1387 -0.2337 0.1524 -0.1891 0.1351 -0.1592 0.1026 -0.1522 0.1058 -0.1212";
```

and the codes

```
mydatanormalized = With[{max = Max@Map[Norm[#] &, mydata, {2}]}, mydata/max];

MatrixPlot[Map[Norm[#] &, mydata, {2}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]

ListVectorDensityPlot[mydata, DataRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 VectorColorFunction -> None, 
 VectorScaling -> "Linear",
 VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, False, False, True}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
   Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), n]], 
 MaxRecursion -> 2]

ListVectorDensityPlot[mydatanormalized, DataRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
 VectorColorFunction -> None, 
 VectorScaling -> "Linear",
 VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
   Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), n]], 
 MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

However, there is a big difference as shown below. In both plots, spurious color regions (exaggeratedly ***opaque***, I think) show up at the boundary. ***They are actually outside the data coordinate range***, $[-1.2,1.2]$. And such distortion looks to suppress the true data in the first plot. However, the original data is nothing special at all in the norm near the boundary (one can easily see by `MatrixPlot` the norm as shown.)

One can restrict the plot range to the original data coordinates

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[mydatanormalized, DataRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}(*,PlotRangeClipping\[Rule]False*), 
 VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorScaling -> "Linear", VectorRange -> All, 
 VectorStyle -> Black, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), n]], 
 MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

for Method 2 and it gets rid of the spurious region (not shown here), although this is not helpful for Method 1. Here, one has to comment out `PlotRangeClipping -> False`. However, one ***needs*** `PlotRangeClipping -> False` for good reasons, otherwise

1. one cannot place labels outside the plotting box (I care about this the most)
2. arrows at the boundary are cut off, like only half of an arrow is shown

So we still need some remedy/workaround here.
How should one correctly plot the data without these weird distortions?
(I came up with an idea but weirdly [got stuck](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241908/11125). Solving that one would do as well.)

Only plot norm:
[image]
Method 1:
[image]
Method 2:
[image]

Comment: According to **Properties & Relations** section of document of `ListVectorDensityPlot` (To be more specific, check the code below the line "Scalar fields can be plotted by themselves with `ListDensityPlot`"), the density isn't scaled linearly. Have you taken this into consideration?

Comment: @xzczd But I am using my own `ColorFunction` that scales linearly with the norm. I feel MMA is plotting something wrong here, like a bug. There's just nothing special at the boundary if one looks at the norm plot. In some other cases, I see singular (very bright color) points at the four corners while norms are actually small and nothing really happens there.

Comment: Actually, the four corners (at least three of them) do show similar wrong behavior in the present post. Just compare with the norm plot.

Comment: @xzczd I found some clue. See my update.

Comment: Interesting. It's a blind spot, I should say. I didn't notice `ListVectorDensityPlot` has drawn _a bit more!_

Comment: Is the behavior confirmed by WRI as a bug?

Comment: @xzczd Oh, I thought tagging 'bugs' is only based on community consensus here and usually someone random initiates. I'm not sure if it's appropriate. Please feel free to remove it.

Comment: Of course sometimes it's based on community consensus, but currently I'm the only one taking part in the discussion and I'm not sure if it's a bug… Better to wait for a moment.

Comment: @xzczd Many thanks to your generous bounty! Let's wait.

Comment: I take the liberty to shorten the `mydata` and modify the corresponding code a bit. (My browser gets stuck when I try selecting the original one by triple clicking it. ) The result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for both methods, a better solution would be to use `RegionFunction` to restrict the plotting region:

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[mydata, DataRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 RegionFunction -> (-1.2 <= #1 <= 1.2 && -1.2 <= #2 <= 1.2 &),
  VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorScaling -> "Linear",
  VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, False, False, True}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
      Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), n]], 
  MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

produces

[image: Method1 with RegionFunction]
and

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[mydatanormalized, DataRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 RegionFunction -> (-1.2 <= #1 <= 1.2 && -1.2 <= #2 <= 1.2 &),
  VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorScaling -> "Linear",
  VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
      Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 π), n]], 
  MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

produces

[image: Method2 with RegionFunction]

In either case, you can remove the thin border around the plotted region using `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't make Method 1 right but indeed improves Method 2. However, it now leaves an awkwardly wider white boundary than the default plot (I can see why). I need to combine/show this plot together with other normal plots with such an outer frame. This one will be conspicuously different. If only we could make it work in the default way...

Comment: I think the reason why methods 1 and 2 don't match is that they actually involve different normalizations: in (1) all norms are computed, their `MinMax` is seen to be say `{MIN,MAX}`, and finally when choosing colors for a given norm `n` the `ColorFunction` sees `(n-MIN)/(MAX-MIN)`, i.e. all values lie in the range [0,1]; what you do in (2) is divide all vectors by the norm of the vector with largest norm, which means the `ColorFunction` will see a maximum norm of 1 but a minimum norm greater than 0 (in your case, about `0.0104509` because the null vector is not in your data)

Comment: As for the extra white border, you can remove it using e.g. `PlotRangePadding -> -0.03`, which for me leaves it essentially as it was before, but this will change the plotting range and I assume it would be equally awkward when sitting next to your other plots. Since you can't trust MMA to make all the right choices by default, my approach in this cases usually involves fixing all of these parameters myself for all of my plots, i.e. standardize plot ranges, range paddings, etc, until all the plots look nicely uniform...

Comment: I take the liberty to edit the code a bit because the structure of `mydata` is modified. The result isn't influenced.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to understand how `ListVectorDensityPlot[]` works in this case. But for my opinion for some presentation it could be better to use something less rainbow, for instance,

```
ListVectorDensityPlot[mydatanormalized, 
 DataRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  VectorColorFunction -> None, 
  VectorScaling -> "Linear",
  VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
      Hue[ArcCos[vy/Sqrt[vx^2 + vy^2]]/(2 \[Pi]), .5 + n/2]], 
  MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't remove the spurious colors/regions. Or you just want to show a different `ColorFunction`?

Comment: @xiaohuamao What do you mean under spurious? In this picture we can see how `ListVectorDensityPlot[]` interpolating data on the boundary.

Comment: @xiaohuamao If I understand it right, Alex is showing a `ColorFunction` with which the wild extrapolation of `ListVectorDensityPlot` isn't that obvious.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are right, and also it shows how Mathematica interpolating data on the border. For my opinion  it is nice picture.