# Cannot access ColorFunction in ListVectorDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, color, slot

Working on a vector field, I'd like to use a `ColorFunction` dependent on both the vector direction and its norm. According to the documentation of `ListVectorDensityPlot`, one has access to `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, s},...`. However, in the codes below with two equivalent plottings, errors occur as if one can not use `vx,vy`. Same for both `data0` and `data1`.

On the other hand, it does work when we delete the `s` entry in `data0` or `data1`. However, I need explicit `s` for another reason: without explicit `s`, it will automatically plot a little beyond the supplied data range, which may cause trouble in [certain cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/241821/11125).

Is there a way to access `vx,vy`?

```
f = {-y, x};
s = Norm[f];
data0 = Table[{f, s}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}];
data1 = Table[{{x, y}, {f, s}}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}];

ListVectorDensityPlot[data1, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
 VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, False, False, True}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, vx, vy, s}, Hue[ArcTan[vx, vy]/(2 \[Pi]), s]]]

ListVectorDensityPlot[data1, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
 VectorRange -> All, VectorStyle -> Black, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, False, False, True}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 \[Pi]), #5] &)]
```